# Magento 1.14 : Maintenance page for different stores

Tags: enterprise-1.14, maintenance

If I have a magento install with several stores, how to configure the errors map, in order to have specific maintenance pages for each store. 
The structures of the stores are `app/design/frontend/theme/` and this theme has four different folders, corresponding to four different stores.
I really appreciate the help you can provide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a magento.flag file, Magento send a 503 and put the website in maintenance.

In the file /errors/processor.php, you can see the function process503() which call the renderPage : '503.phtml'.
In this function, you can check the current store and call different render according to the storeId.